# How to use string retrieved from back-end as template in Angular2?

Tags: angular

In an Angular2 app, I'd like to use ajax to retrieve a html tag string from back-end and use it as template in Angular2.

```
// The str I get from server by ajax is:
var str = "<my-hero [hero]=\"hero\"></my-hero>"
```

When the app is already running in the browser. If I $('myHeroParent').append(str). This code won't work.

How can you make this work? Is it called dynamic loading component?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a template, pass the string to `$compile` to create a DOM element: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: This is Angular1.X. Is there a similar thing for angular2?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can send this particular html as a template in a component like this

```
angular.module('MenuApp')
.component('itemset1', {
templateUrl: '<my-hero [hero]=\"hero\"></my-hero>',
});
```