# Angular2 compile the html in Runtime

Tags: javascript, html, angular, compilation

I am problem with Angular2 to integration with CMS.
I need to compile the HTML in run time (JIT) and transform it to a template-component. Is there any way to configure the component-template to some reference in the dom?

All this because my CMS generates the HTML dynamic and i cant compile the html this in build.

The problem is similiar to this case, but in angular2:
[How to use string retrieved from back-end as template in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499827/how-to-use-string-retrieved-from-back-end-as-template-in-angular2/40500239)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular/38888009#38888009

Comment: Hello Gunter, thanks for your attetion. I do not know if I was clear.
For example, i have this snippet code in my doom:
<body>
<div id="content"> {{text}}<div>
</body>
<script src="angular2.xxx>

This snippet has already been built by CMS.So i need to convert this to my template.
But in the component annotation i can put only the templateURL or HTML CODE inline.

I need something like that:
@Componenttemplate:"Div id=Content" (something like selector but for template)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2)

Comment: This should be a fundamental feature in Angular 2+ but unfortunately, in the name of performance, it lost the main feature.